# How to check if a list of records contains a specific record in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I'm new to Erlang and am trying to write a function that when passed a Point record (an x,y coordinate) and a list of Point records (a list of x,y coordinates), returns true if the Point record with the specified x and y coordinates is an element (i.e. already exists) in the list and false otherwise.

Here's the definition of the point record:

```
-record(point, {x, y})
```

This is the signature of the function:

```
contains_point(Point, List)
```

I tried looking up similar questions and in the Erlang docs, but haven't found what I'm looking for.

I also tried the following code:

```
contains_point(Point, List)->
    Found = fun(Point) -> lists:member(Point, List) end,
    case lists:any(Found, List) of
        true ->
            yes;
        false ->
            no
    end.
```

But got the warning messages, "variable 'Point' shadowed in 'fun'" and "variable 'Point' is unused."

Would appreciate any help with this, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function has multiple problems, hinted at by the unused and shadowed variable warnings.

```erlang
contains_point(Point, List) ->
    Found = fun(Point) -> lists:member(Point, List) end,
    case lists:any(Found, List) of
        true ->
            yes;
        false ->
            no
    end.
```

The `lists:any/2` function takes as its first argument a predicate function that's called with each element of the second argument, a list, until either the predicate returns true or the list is exhausted. The predicate here is the anonymous function `Found`, which returns the result of passing its list element argument to `lists:member/2`. But the `lists:member/2` function also traverses its list argument, returning true if its first argument matches a list element or false otherwise, which means the `Found` predicate checks the entire list every time `lists:any/2` calls it, which is quite inefficient.

Your function also returns `yes` or `no`, but according to your description it's supposed to return a boolean.

The easiest way to fix your function is to return the result of `lists:member/2`, since it traverses a list looking for a match:

```erlang
contains_point(Point, List) ->
    lists:member(Point, List).
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use the `lists` module, you can write the function to traverse the list itself and check for matches:

```erlang
contains_point(_, []) -> false;
contains_point(Point, [Point|_]) -> true;
contains_point(Point, [_|Tail]) ->
    contains_point(Point, Tail).
```

1. The first clause matches the empty list and so returns false.
2. The second clause provides the true case, since its first argument and the head of the list are both the same `Point` value and so they match.
3. The third clause matches when `Point` doesn't match the head of the list; it calls `contains_point/2` recursively with `Point` and the tail of list.

This approach is essentially what `lists:member/2` does.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
fun(Point) -> lists:member(Point, List) end
```

That is a definition of an anonymous function, which is known as a `fun` in erlang.  When you define any function, anonymous or otherwise, you specify parameter variables, e.g. Point, then when you call the function erlang will assign the arguments you specify in the function call to the parameter variables in the function definition.  You can then use the parameter variables inside the function definition to accomplish whatever you desire.

Notably, that anonymous function definition is equivalent to:

```
 fun(X) -> lists:member(X, List) end
```

In other words, the *parameter* variables in a function definition have no relation to any other variables outside the function definition.  Erlang gives you two warnings to that effect:

```
variable 'Point' shadowed in 'fun'"
```

That means you used the same variable name in this function parameter list:

```
contains_point(Point, List) -> ...
```

as you did in this (anonymous) function parameter list:

```
fun(Point) -> lists:member(Point, List) end
```

yet they are not related to each other.

```
 variable 'Point' is unused."
```

You get that warning because the parameter variable Point here:

```
 contains_point(Point, List)
```

is never used inside the body of the `contains_point()` function definition.

You *can* do this:

```
do_stuff(Point) ->
    X = fun() -> io:format("~w~n", [Point]) end,
    X().
```

In that case, the fun does not define a parameter variable that "shadows" another variable, so the `Point` variable inside the anonymous function definition is the same `Point` variable in the `do_stuff()` parameter list.